# Is there anyway to do automatic translation from English to Arabic for a WooCommerce site?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation, language-translation

I'm wondering if there is any way to do automatic translation for all pages & products & elements via a plugin or via a code snippet for example to translate content from English to Arabic for my WooCommerce Site.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this free plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/gtranslate/

Also there are few premium plugins are listed here:
https://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/9-best-translation-plugins-for-wordpress-websites/